# Combine top and join in sql

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two tables. One for employees

```
LAST_NAME                     SALARY DEPARTMENT_ID
------------------------- ---------- -------------
Vargas                          2500            50
Zlotkey                        10500            50
Abel                           11000            80
Taylor                          8600            80
```

One for department name

```
DEPARTMENT_ID DEPARTMENT_NAME               
------------- ------------------------------
50            Shipping
80            Sales
```

I want to select the top three employees who have the max salary in the employees table.After get, I want to get their department_name. Resulting like this.

```
LAST_NAME                     SALARY DEPARTMENT_NAME
------------------------- ---------- -------------
Abel                          11000       Sales
Zlotkey                       10500       Shipping
Taylor                         8600       Sales
```

I had try this:

```
SELECT last_name, salary, department_id, ROWNUM as RANK
FROM (SELECT last_name, salary, department_id
FROM employees
ORDER BY salary DESC)
WHERE ROWNUM <= 3;
```

But i don't know how to use join on to get department_name.

Platform: windows10

SQLDeveloper version: 18.01

Comment: (1) your logic is not clear: Do you want all the salaries of the employees from the department with the largest salary sum? (2) It's not clear what RDBMS you're using. Are you using MS SQL Server? (3) Could you share whatever you've already tried? It seems like this might be pretty simple using a sub-query.

Comment: What's the expected result if there's a tie in third position? I.e. two different employees having the same third highest salary.

Comment: `... order by salary desc fetch first 3 rows only` / `with ties`

Comment: @Zack Thanks, I not think a lot sorry.

Comment: @jarlh Thanks, you remind me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using window functions:

```
select e.last_name, e.salary, d.department_name
from (select e.*, max(sum_salary) over () as max_sum_salary

      from (select e.*, sum(e.salary) over (partition by department_id) as sum_salary
            from employees e
            ) e
     ) e join
     department d
     on e.department_id = d.department_id
where max_sum_salary = sum_salary
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 1):

You can do `JOIN` with subquery :

```
SELECT e.LAST_NAME, e.SALARY, d.DEPARTMENT_NAME
FROM employees e INNER JOIN
     department d
     ON d.DEPARTMENT_ID = e.DEPARTMENT_ID
WHERE e.DEPARTMENT_ID = (SELECT e1.DEPARTMENT_ID
                         FROM employees e1
                         ORDER BY e1.SALARY DESC
                         FETCH FIRST 1 ROWS ONLY
                        );
```

EDIT : If you want only three employees then you can do :

```
SELECT e.LAST_NAME, e.SALARY, d.DEPARTMENT_NAME
FROM employees e INNER JOIN
     department d
     ON d.DEPARTMENT_ID = e.DEPARTMENT_ID
ORDER BY e.SALARY DESC
FETCH FIRST 3 ROWS ONLY
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
select top(3)LAST_NAME, SALARY, DEPARTMENT_NAME 
from employees e
inner join  department  d on e.DEPARTMENT_ID = d.DEPARTMENT_ID
where d.DEPARTMENT_NAME = 'sales'
order by SALARY desc
```